# C#: Is it possible to cast a generic type for a type constraint?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a factory method that determines the object to return based on the generic type in the method call

```cs
public IDbStrategy<T> GetDefaultStrategy<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DbModel))
        ? new DefaultModelDbStrategy<T>()
        : new DefaultDbStrategy<T>();
}
```

the `DefaultModelDbStrategy` as a type constraint of `where T : DbModel` but the `DefaultDbStrategy` does not. I am getting a compiler error when trying to use `T` as the generic type for `DefaultModelDbStrategy` because the compiler doesn't know that `T` is a `DbModel`. Is there a way to ensure my compiler that the generic argument passed in does indeed derive from `DbModel` as the reflection statement above asserts?

Thanks

Comment: @Sweeper, I don't want the caller to have to know which method to use

Comment: If you cant constrain the generic method, the only thing you can do is write an analyzer for compile time, or do a runtime check, and use reflection. The later is usually a sign generics is the wrong choice, however, by your design and wishes you don't have much choice

Comment: It would be great if you could have provided a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without reflection. Because `T` is statically resolved at compile time, the compiler would need to instantiate type `DefaultModelDbStrategy<object>` (if T is `object`), but this is an illegal type. The types used within a method need to be resolved when the method is JITed, and not only when a particular line is executed.

There's a workaround using reflection though: You can do

```
(IDbStrategy<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DefaultModelDbStrategy<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
```

This creates an instance of DefaultModelDbStrategy, with the given T. It will throw a runtime error if T doesn't satisfy the constraints.

Comment: And of course you would cast the expression from `Activator.CreateInstance(...)` (I think you are missing the last `)`) to `IDbStrategy<T>` in order to make things compile (the compile-time return type of `CreateInstance` is `object`, of course).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, of course. And I would probably not write it in a ternary then, but that's syntactic sugar.